# Handle logo text color from admin section

Tags: admin, color-picker

Hi as per my requirement I need to have

> Color Picker option for Logo Text

see image
 [image: see the below image]

> For ***TEXT2*** I need to have color picker option which can be managed from
>   admin dashboard

I tried searching for plugins or custom code but not succeded is this possible if so please help me with procedure thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is your _question_ here? :) What had you tried and how far you got?

Comment: My question is how to provide option for admin to change logo text color changing according to his requirement and I didn't try to do this coz I am not having any small idea to achieve this I am a newbie

Comment: I would recommend to split this into smaller more actionable questions and add your progress as you go. (For example "I need to add a color picker, and that is what I found and tried so far...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up filling my requirement using this [PLUGIN](https://wordpress.org/plugins/font).It Does what I really needed.